# Trouble shoot a dynamic linq query in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I have a regular linq query that is written as such:

```
    Clients.Where (c => c.EmailReturnUndeliverable == false || 
                        c.ClientBadStanding_TF == false)
```

I would like to dynamically write the query as such:

```
    Clients.Where ("EmailReturnUndeliverable = false Or ClientBadStanding_TF = false")
```

I have reviewed [Scott G's article on Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) and it looks like my syntax is correct.

However, I cannot get the 2nd query to run.

**My setup:**

VS 10 / ASP.NET App

**Steps I have taken:**

- added the DynamicLibrary.cs file that Scott references into my 'App_Code' folder
- attempted to use the Using statement: using System.Linq.Dynamic; (as used in Scott's 'DynamicLINQCSharp' project) but am getting a missing assembly reference error.

Anyone have any council on what I am missing or how to get the using statement to clear up?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact error? What does it say is missing?

Answer (score 0):

In case if your CLients is a list, can you try

```
 Clients.AsQueryable().Where ("EmailReturnUndeliverable = false Or ClientBadStanding_TF = false")
```

If I am not mistaken DynamicLibrary.cs has functions which can we applied to IQueryable